# How to track Intercom chat as an event in GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, intercom

Love Intercom but can not figure out how to track actual chat ans event in GA

Any work around for that as seems like they dont support this natively

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have Google Tag manager installed?

Answer (score 4):

Intercom provides a few hooks that you can use to make a call to your analytics provider.

The first is `onShow` [onShow Javascript API](https://developers.intercom.com/docs/intercom-javascript#section-intercomonshow):

```
Intercom('onShow', function() {
    // record event
});
```

The second is `onUnreadCountChange` [onUnreadCountChange Javascript API](https://developers.intercom.com/docs/intercom-javascript#section-intercomonshow):

```
Intercom('onUnreadCountChange', function(unreadCount) {
    // record event
});
```

You might be able to work something out by tracking these events, though I'm not sure exactly when each of them will fire (message in, out, auto message, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

Intercom now allows you to connect directly your Google Analytics Property to your Intercom account.

Some events will then be automatically pushed to your Google Analytics.

Everything is explained here : https://www.intercom.com/help/apps-in-intercom/apps/google-analytics-track-how-visitors-interact-with-the-messenger

Answer (score -3):

Intercom works through an iframe. You won't be able to track any activity in it.

Comment: Just FYI - just because Intercom is in an iFrame doesn't mean they couldn't bubble up events to be consumed from your website or Google Analytics. Event Listeners are one possibility.